# Magento Admin URL [Permission with Whitelist IP]

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security, htaccess

I'm trying to protect the URL of my login admin page.

It's possible to allow only my ip to this page?

And if another IP tries to open the admin login page, there is an unauthorized permission.

I tried to add :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/ADMIN_PANEL_LOCATION [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^81.82.83.84
```

or :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^81.82.83.84
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?admin/ - [L,R=403]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you add the OR for index.php in your first example, it will work.

Here is an example of what is working for me:

```
#Restrict admin access
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?ADMIN_PANEL_LOCATION/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^99\.999\.999\.999
```